# Android Studio - Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarButtonStyle'

Tags: android, android-studio

I`m experiencing a weird problem....

/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:877: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarButtonStyle'.

In theory all the sdk`s and add-ons are ok. Does anybody have an idea what might be?
----build.gradle-- Using sdk 19.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

}﻿
```

Answer (score -1):

Toady,I also read Android sample full screen Demo,I find same problem with     you.
  when I read all res files ,I understand.I can write same code with demo  ,without problems .there are some steps:
  1.create you own styles file and write it:
  sample:

```
 <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle -->
  <style name=\"btnbar\">`enter code here`
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
 </style>
```

2.*create attrs.xml,and write it with ButtonBar attr.sample is that:*

```
 <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle -->
 enter code here 2dp 5dp 2dp 0dp 
 <declare-styleable name="ButtonBarContainerTheme">
    <attr name="metaButtonBarStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle" format="reference" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

Comment: 1.create you own styles file and write it:
  sample:
    <pre> <code>

Comment: please take a bit care with your code formatting (every line needs at least 4 Spaces at the beginning) - without, the answer was unreadable :-)